# Build and run error on Unity: Gradle Build Failed

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I'm trying to build and run a unity game on my android device. When doing so, I get an error that says:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
>   C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=->Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

I checked the file path and everything seems to be there and intact. I have no idea what else would help to fix this error, so if you could help me that would be great. Thanks!